# How much can iTunes download on my MacBook? Not talking about iCloud

Tags: itunes

How many gigabytes does iTunes occupy on MacBook? I am downloading a lot my CDs. Is there a limit? How can I see if I'm getting too close to full capacity?

Answer (score 1):

You are only constrained by the storage capacity available on your MacBooks internal storage.

iTunes creates its library for storing media and metadata in `~/Music/iTunes` directory by default.

Comment: In addition, there are five import encoding settings in iTunes (Preferences > General > Import Settings...) which can affect the size of the files created by the process. The available encoders are AAC, AIFF, Apple Lossless, MP3 and WAV. All but the Apple Lossless encoder allows you to configure various aspects of the encoding process, some of which can make the resultant file larger or smaller. See [this page about import settings](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19608?locale=en_US) at Apple Support.